# Textbox autocomplete function not autocompleting in C# WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

Im having problems with this simple function on a textbox.. I have a winforms application, with a textbox, set up to autocomplete like this:

```
if (rbSerialNumSearch.Checked)
{
       txtSerialNum.Enabled = true;
       AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

       //Test data
       data.Add("555-777-333");
       data.Add("222-333-444");
       data.Add("111-222-333");

       txtSerialNum.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;

       txtSerialNum.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;

       txtSerialNum.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

But it is not working. Nothing appears when i type in the textbox? If i i specify strings directly to the textbox collection property (in design mode), it works fine, but when i try to add strings programmatically, nothing happends?

Thanks in advance..

ENTIRE CODE FOR FORM HERE:

```
namespace GUI
{
    public partial class UpdateEquipmentForm : Form
    {
        EquipmentManager em;
        ProductManager pm;
        CategoryManager cm;

        public UpdateEquipmentForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            em = new EquipmentManager();
            pm = new ProductManager();
            cm = new CategoryManager();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbCategorySearch.Checked)
            {
                List<Equipment> equipments = em.GetAllEquipmentInStock().Where(eq => eq.Product.Category_Id == (int)cbChooseCategory.SelectedValue).ToList();

                var resultset = (from eq in equipments
                                 select new { eq.Product.ProductNameNum, eq.Id, eq.SerialNumber, eq.InvoiceNumber, eq.CreatedDate, eq.ExpiryDate, eq.FirstUseDate }).ToList();

                dgvResult.DataSource = resultset;
            }
            if (rbProductsSearch.Checked)
            {
                List<Equipment> equipments = em.GetAllEquipmentInStock().Where(eq => eq.Product.Id == (int)cbChooseType.SelectedValue).ToList();

                var resultset = (from eq in equipments
                                 select new { eq.Product.ProductNameNum, eq.Id, eq.SerialNumber, eq.InvoiceNumber, eq.CreatedDate, eq.ExpiryDate, eq.FirstUseDate }).ToList();

                dgvResult.DataSource = resultset;
            }
            if (rbSerialNumSearch.Checked)
            {
                List<Equipment> equipments = em.GetAllEquipmentInStock();

                var resultset = (from eq in equipments
                                 where eq.SerialNumber.Contains(txtSearchEquipment.Text)
                                 select new { eq.Product.ProductNameNum, eq.Id, eq.SerialNumber, eq.InvoiceNumber, eq.CreatedDate, eq.ExpiryDate, eq.FirstUseDate }).ToList();

                dgvResult.DataSource = resultset;
            }
        }

        private void rbCategorySearch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbCategorySearch.Checked)
            {
                cbChooseCategory.Enabled = true;
                cbChooseCategory.DataSource = cm.GetAllActiveCategories();
                cbChooseCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
                cbChooseCategory.ValueMember = "Id";
            }
            else
            {
                cbChooseCategory.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void rbProductsSearch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbProductsSearch.Checked)
            {
                cbChooseType.Enabled = true;
                cbChooseType.DataSource = pm.GetAllActiveProducts();
                cbChooseType.DisplayMember = "ProductNameNum";
                cbChooseType.ValueMember = "Id";
            }
            else
            {
                cbChooseType.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void rbSerialNumSearch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbSerialNumSearch.Checked)
            {
                txtSerialNum.Enabled = true;
                AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

                data.Add("555-777-333");
                data.Add("222-333-444");
                data.Add("111-222-333");

                txtSerialNum.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;

                txtSerialNum.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;

                txtSerialNum.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            }
            else
            {
                txtSerialNum.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you execute this code? and do you execute it?

Comment: The code is executed in a radiobutton checkedchanged event. I have three search chriterias, which are selected by radiobuttons, this being one of them.

Comment: On which event this code is fired if (rbSerialNumSearch.Checked) {} ?

Comment: Initially, i tried to get the serialnumbers from a database, and add them to autocompletesource of the textbox. But since nothing appeared, i tried to make a simple example with hardcoded data, in order to find the source of the problem..

Comment: If I take this code and apply it without conditions to a bare bone text box It works as expected. So I suppose that you have something in your code that reverts this block of code. Check if there is a code flow that leads to a reversion of these settings

Comment: Vivek: Yes.. In void rbSerialNumSearch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Steve: Hmm.. Can't seem to see what should be reverting it..It's all pretty simple code. Thats why it's so odd. I will provide the entire code for the form above..

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.. Really stupid of me. I was referencing the wrong textbox :-( The one i should be referencing is called txtSearchSerial and not txtSerialNum. Doh !

Appreciate the effort guys..thanks.

Comment: That's funny :) no problem everyone makes mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can set a break point to

```
     txtSerialNum.Enabled = true;
```

I think this application never run into this block.

Or after this code, you re-set the binding of txtSerialNum.

Comment: Tried debugging. Executes the code fine, when selecting radiobutton :-/